# systemd service failing (203/EXEC)

Tags: linux, centos7, systemd

I have a custom systemd service (created using [this tutorial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd) to modify my screen resolution to a custom value on startup.

I am having issues with the service failing to start (code=203/EXEC).

To start, I have tried all solutions to the following existing topics with no luck:

[Fixing a systemd service 203/EXEC failure (no such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776003/fixing-a-systemd-service-203-exec-failure-no-such-file-or-directory)

[Systemd service failing on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256227/systemd-service-failing-on-startup)

[Unable to run Gunicorn as service in systemd 203/EXEC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117100/unable-to-run-gunicorn-as-service-in-systemd-203-exec)

My .service file is this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set resolution to 1920x1080

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fixres.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
```

journalctl output states that the service "Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/fixres.sh: Permission denied".  However, I have no issue running the script by myself with just `bash /usr/bin/fixres.sh`.

Other things of note: this is in CentOS7 running in VirtualBox

Can anyone find a mistake that I made, or possibly give me some more troubleshooting options?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I did the sensible thing and actually googled my error message from journalctl, yielding [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209097/systemd-failed-at-step-exec-spawning-script-permission-denied).  After modifying the permissions of my script for execution, I get a new error in journalctl stating that the script can't open the display.

There is currently a comment on the question suggesting exactly this.

If I run `xhost`, I get the following output:

```
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:root
SI:localuser:<username>
```

I'm unfamiliar with this aspect, but it seems like root has access to xhost.

The other option suggested was exporting the display.  I am not sure what this would accomplish.  I am not trying to access the display from a remote system.  Or, is that how linux interprets this?

Update:

So, adding `Environment=DISPLAY=:0` to the unit file allows me to start the service from the command line.  However, it still fails on boot.  I have a feeling that I need to wait for another service to start.

I have tried adding `After=gdm.service`, but this fails as well.  Are there any other services I may need to wait for?

Comment: `However, I have no issue running the script by myself` - but systemd has trouble running the script. Because it can't access desktop. You need to `export DISPLAY=....` and set `xhost +root` or similar on your xserver to allow access as root. Try running the script as root.

Comment: Also inspect logs by using `systemctl status` and inspecting `journalctl`. You should find that `xrandr` could not ocnnect to display

Comment: I've updated my question to include results from your suggestions, as well as an additional question.

Comment: chmod a+x /usr/bin/fixres.sh  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203371/run-script-sh-vs-bash-script-sh-permission-denied

Comment: `it still fails on boot` - `After=gdm.service` will be ok, but probably initilialization race will be the issue. Well, I would just dirty add `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 5`. Do you have a single user on your PC? The `systemctl --user` everything, should run after the user logs in into graphical interface, so the graphical interface is already existing. Actually the proper way of achieving what you want, would be to edit `~/.xinitrc` or /etc/X11/xinitrc or just add a script to autostart to gnome. Using systemd for running service to change desktop resolution - it's not the  tool for that.

Comment: Based on Kamil Cuk's and jww's comments, I will close this question here.  Thanks to Kamil for clueing me in on the gnome autostart script method.  This is what I'm using now ([for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247706/start-script-when-gnome-starts-up)).  I am still seeing some issues there, but I will ask the question over on Stack Exchange.