# Running python file as service results in exit code status 1

Tags: python, error-handling, systemd

**Summary:**

A python script using apshceduler fails to load as service with exit code 203/EXEC. Important to note that same script designed to run every 10 seconds using `while True:` syntax runs very well as daemon (service).

**Details**

I wrote a simple test.py program. It appends some a.txt file every 10 seconds with "some" string. When I try to run it as daemon service as it comes out with error code. . In itself without using it as daemon (service) it works fine. Also if I don't use apscheduler in writing the test.py file then the service runs smoothly. 
I will put all the code here for details including the `systemctl status`

**Code**

*test.py file*

```
import os, glob, shutil
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
sched = BlockingScheduler()
def test():
    appendFile = open(r'/home/sangharsh/code/a.txt', 'a')
    appendFile.write("Jai Bhim \n" )
    appendFile.close()
sched.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=10)

sched.start()
```

Its located @ - /home/sangharsh/code/workingWithFiles/
To run it as daemon I create service file -

*service config file*

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python3 /home/sangharsh/code/workingWithFiles/test.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This file is located @ - /lib/systemd/system/

I restart the daemon-

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then enable the test.service file -

```
sudo systemctl enable test.service
```

and to start the test.service

```
sudo systemctl start test.service
```

and to scheck the status

```
sudo systemctl status test.service
```

The `systemctl status` shows:

```
● test.service - Test Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/test.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-07-09 23:28:10 IST; 13s ago
  Process: 5272 ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python3 /home/sangharsh/code/workingWithF
 Main PID: 5272 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 09 23:28:10 sangharsh-HP-240-G4-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started Test Service
Jul 09 23:28:10 sangharsh-HP-240-G4-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: test.service: Main p
Jul 09 23:28:10 sangharsh-HP-240-G4-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: test.service: Failed
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54120376/3604513) question. I tried the options but it doesn't help.
And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54120376/3604513) is not much applicable as it has permission issues.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54120376/3604513): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472950/361166 ```

Please guide.